How to make my Linux router forward traffic over a NAT properly?
I have a Linux box that I'm using as a router with a NAT. It is connected upstream on 192.168.1.x/24 and inside the NAT on 10.0.x.x/16. I am also running a DHCP and DNS server on it, though those seem to be working.
When I connect a client system to the 10.0.x.x network, it gets an IP but traffic isn't being forwarded to the 192.168.1.x gateway (or maybe isn't forwarding responses back). When running ping 8.8.8.8 on the client system and wireshark on the router, I see the ICMP messages from the client to 8.8.8.8, but no response.
How can I fix my router so that it properly forwards and receives traffic? It was working for a long time but recently broke for unknown reasons (the router is actually a workstation and gets other use).
Running cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward outputs 1.
The output of iptables -t nat -L gives
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere            !127.0.0.0/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  all  --  10.92.215.0/24      !10.92.215.0/24       /* generated for LXD network lxdbr0 */
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.17.0.0/16        anywhere            
LIBVIRT_PRT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere    


I got it working by adding the forwarding rules to iptables with
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i enp5s0 -o wlp6s0 -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlp6s0 -o enp5s0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

where wlp6s0 is the outbound interface and enp5s0 is the internal interface.
